# Two closest points in Manhattan distance

Tags: algorithm

I'm wondering about Manhattan distance. It is very specific, and (I don't know if it's a good word) simple. For example when we are given a set of **n** points in this metric, then it is very easy to find the distance between two farthest points, in linear time. But is it also easy to find two closest points?

I heard, that there exists universal algorithm for finding two closest points in any metric, but it's complicated. I'm wondering if in this situation (Manhattan metric) it is possible to use special properties of this distance and come up with an easier algorithm, that will be more friendly in implementation?

EDIT: **n** points on a plane, and lets say **-10^9 <= x,y <= 10^9** for all points.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778044/finding-the-distance-between-two-sets-in-manhattan-distance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about `n` points on a plane, find among the coordinates the minimal and maximal values of `x` and `y` coordinates. Create a matrix sized `maxX-minX` x `maxY-minY`, such that all points are representable by a cell in the matrix. Fill the matrix with the `n` given points (not all cells will be filled, set `NaN` there, for example). Scan the matrix - shortest distance is between adjacent filled cells in the matrix (there are might be several such pairs).

Comment: I'm sorry, I just edited my question. Lets say x,y are big enough so we can not create such matrix.

Comment: There are methods to store sparse matrices without wasting much space: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix